# What is this model number please?

Tags: technic, set-identification

I don't have the instructions for this and I have no idea what model number this is.

Can anyone identify it?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

It appears to be a partially-constructed [8242-1 Slammer Turbo](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=8242-1)

[image]

Comment: I even think that part of the launcher is visible at the top of the picture